# Modeling closed hydraulic cycle in OpenModelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I'd like to model a closed hydraulic cycle as one can find in the Modelica Standard Library/Fluid/Examples/HeatingSystem. With the heating system as well as with my (minimalistic) example I've got the same problem: The system is overdetermined.
You can find the HeatingSystem as a "bad example" in the following lecture, so I guess this is a well known problem, but I don't really get the point.
http://www.modprod.liu.se/MODPROD2011/1.252944/modprod2011-day2-talk3-Keynote-Francesco-Casella-Control-and-Modelica.pdf (page 20)

My example is:

a pump

```
model producer
  pipe_flange w,k;
  parameter Real a,b,c;
equation
  w.p = k.p + a * k.Vp ^ 2 + b * k.Vp + c;
end producer;
```

a resistence

```
model consumer
  pipe_flange w,k;
  parameter Real rho;
  parameter Real d_i;
  parameter Real zeta;
equation
  k.p = w.p - rho / 2 * ((w.Vp * 4) / 3.14 * d_i ^ 2) ^ 2 * zeta;
end consumer;
```

they are connected with a

```
connector pipe_flange
  Real p;
  flow Real Vp;
end pipe_flange;
```

The whole system is:

```
model System
  consumer consumer1(rho = 1000, d_i = 0.06, zeta = 0.5);
  producer producer1(a = -740741, b = -19630, c = 1070);
equation
  connect(consumer1.w,producer1.w);
  connect(consumer1.k,producer1.k);
end System;
```

Can anybody give me a hint what the problem is all about?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your system is **overdetermined**?  I'm; not sure how this can be since both your `producer` and `consumer` models are underdetermined.

As a general rule, the number of equations you need in a component will be equal to the number of flow variables across all its connectors + the number of internal variables (parameters do not count) + the number of outputs.

By this method, your `producer` model should have 2 equations (because it has 2 flow variable across all its connectors).  Similarly, your `consumer` model should have 2 equations (Because it has two flow variables across all its connectors).  So I don't see how you can generate too many equations.

Your model is also tricky because you are modeling the flow of momentum through your system (indicated by the presence of velocity on your connector as a flow variable).  But your potential variable is pressure.  There is no tracking of mass in your problem (as there usually is).

So, in summary, your component models definitely have an issue because they are "unbalanced" (according to the Modelica Specification) since they do not have the right number of equations.  But even on a "physical" level, your formulation (pressure and velocity) is unusual in my experience and it seems to me that it could lead to problems as well once the equation balance issue is overcome.

Comment: P.S. - Sorry for the delayed response.  I must have somehow overlooked this post before.  In fact, I thought I had already answered it.

Comment: The same question was asked on [openmodelicainterest](http://www.mail-archive.com/openmodelicainterest@ida.liu.se/msg01352.html) if you want to read what others said

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps to introduce a so called **[loop-breaker](https://www.google.com/search?q=modelica%20loop%20breaker)** component. 
For a closed hydraulic cycle this could be an [expansion vessel](https://www.google.com/search?q=modelica%20expansion%20vessel) or [storage tank](https://www.google.com/search?q=modelica%20loop%20breaker%20storage%20tank) with a variable level 
(such a component will also exist in reality).