# How do I avoid circular equality errors in a closed media circuit? (modelica)

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I'm attempting to build a model of a pumped water heat exchange loop in modelica using thermal.fluid library components (doing my compiling in OpenModelica). The inlet of the constant-volume pump connects to a flow port from a heated pipe component, which is ostensibly the "last" stage in the circuit which is driven by the pump, and so the loop is completed.

This system worked when my media flowed from an ambient source, through the pump, through the system, and out to an ambient sink, but now that I've "completed the circuit," the simulation fails and I receive "circular equality" errors. This makes a modicum of sense physically, as pressure-type variables need a baseline to reference, but it seems that the friction-based elements in my system would create pressure losses through the system, and the pump would operate normally, as pressures would arrive at zero in the piping leading up to the pump.

Any ideas on how to clear these "circular equality" errors, or particular pitfalls I should be looking out for? Could it be that the constant-volume pump operation is interfering with the pressure calculations, and I should use the ideal pump library component?

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10946041/874701

Comment: some good advice on modeling thermo-fluid systems: http://simulationresearch.lbl.gov/modelica/userGuide/bestPractice.html#thermo-fluid-systems (Make sure to read the part 2.4.4 with the expansion vessel, I believe it might help in your case).

Comment: This is indeed a possible duplicate of that one, although she didn't mention the circular equalities issue at compile time. I'll need to investigate. I think my water media model doesn't have a thermal expansion coefficient (intentionally) listed, but I realize it might be inherited and not an explicit parameter.  I'll look into the LBL guide - we decided not to use the modelica.fluid library (or the LBL Buildings fluid library, which I believe is based on modelica.fluid) because we were having trouble compiling with those components in OpenModelica, but the theory is sound.

Comment: I believe it is not an exact duplicate, but still close or related. Even with media without thermal expanison it might be good to have a component model like the expansion vessel, because it can break up the circular equality.

Comment: Knowing very little about your problem, it sounds like the same kind of situation you have when you build an electrical system without a ground.  You end up with a "free body mode" where your equations only allow you to solve for the deltas (in pressure in your case) across components rather than the absolute values.  As you hint at, you need something to define a reference (like a mechanical or electrical ground).

Comment: Is there a "grounding" component in in the base libraries that works with the thermal.fluidheatflow components? I tried adding the  .fluidheatflow.sources.absolutepressure to the circuit, but it didn't solve the issue--I assume something that can vary volume would help, but the only components I'm aware of for that are in the Modelica.Fluid library (which I understand are not fully implementable in OpenModelica, and aren't port-compatible with the thermal.fluidheatflow library).